# Log4net not writing logs to specified path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, log4net

I am working with log for net i  have below LOg4Net.config file code.But It is not writing logs to defined path .Am i doing anything wrong.Shall i miss anything??

**Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

<log4net debug="true">
<appender name="InfoRollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Temp\Logs\FileTransferService\Info.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <!--<threshold value="INFO" />-->
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO"></levelMin>
    <levelMax value="WARN"></levelMax>
  </filter>
  <filter class="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>

<appender name="ErrorRollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Temp\Logs\FileTransferService\Error.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <!--<threshold value="ERROR" />-->
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="ERROR"></levelMin>
    <levelMax value="FATAL"></levelMax>
  </filter>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="InfoRollingLogFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="ErrorRollingLogFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="trace" />
</root>

<!--<logger name="CustomLogger">
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="InfoRollingLogFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="ErrorRollingLogFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="trace" />
</logger>-->

 </log4net>
</configuration>
```

**Assembly Info Code:**

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

**Output Directory :**

Copy always

Comment: Does that path have the appropriate rights? Log4net needs to be have create, read and write rights.

Comment: yes full admin rights checked already

Comment: In the appeder 'ErrorRollingLogFileAppender' you are showing only ERROR and FATAL.  Perhaps there is not any of this severity messages (filter type)